# How can I create a beacon frame without encryption in scapy?

Tags: python, encryption, frame, scapy, beacon

I'm trying to create a `beacon frame` without any encryption in scapy. So when I'm sending the frame, the access point should be shown as `open`.

This was my first attempt:

```
dot11 = Dot11(type=0, subtype=8, addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', addr2=str(RandMAC()), addr3=str(RandMAC()))
beacon = Dot11Beacon(cap='ESS+privacy')
essid = Dot11Elt(ID='SSID',info='AP NAME', len=7)
#rsn = Dot11Elt(ID=48, info='[...]')


frame = RadioTap() / dot11 / beacon / essid
```

The out commented RSN informations represent the encryption (WPA2), afaik. 
So I just left it out in hope that there won't be an encryption anymore.
But it is still displayed as an encrypted AP.

**Query**

How can I change the beacon frame that the (not existing) access point is unencrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the privacy field in beacon editing this line:

```
beacon = Dot11Beacon(cap='ESS')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.